# How to add buttons into each cell of Gridview in Android?

Tags: android, gridview

Am trying to develop an android app. I use a grid view in it and I want to place one button each in each of the cells. Now I entered some values into the grid view using List. I will show it :

```
    GridView gv;           //
    List<String> array;    // Declaration

    gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);     //
    array = new ArrayList<String>();                  //   Initialization

    array.add("1");       //
    array.add("2");       //
    array.add("3");       //  adding values to grid view 

    gv.setAdapter(new ListArray(MainActivity.this, array));
```

Is it possible to add buttons instead of these values ? Please explain the steps with an example.